# I want to prove some theorem using Prolog, however, it always returns "Out of global stack"

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, theorem-proving

I'm doing AI homework of proving the group theory in algebra.

The theorem can be represented as follows:

```
A1. i(e,X) = X                   (identity)
A2. i(X, e) = X                  (identity)
A3. i(comp(X),X) = e             (complement)
A4. i(X, comp(X)) = e            (complement)
A5. i(X, i(Y,Z)) = i(i(X,Y),Z)   (associativity)

THEOREM: If G is a group such that for every X,
A6. i(X,X) = e,
then G is commutative, i.e., for every X; Y ,
i(X,Y) = i(Y,X):

and the commutative part can be represented as 
A7. i(a, b, c)                          clause derived from negated conclusion
A8. -i(b, a, c)                         clause derived from negated conclusion
```

And I converted them into Prolog format as follows:

```
% A7
i(a, b, c).
% A1
i(e, X, X) .
%A2
i(X, e, X).
% A3
i(comp(X), X, e).
% A4
i(X, comp(X), e).
% A51
i(U, Z, W) :- i(X, Y, U), i(Y, Z, V), i(X, V, W).
% A52
i(X, V, W) :- i(X, Y, U), i(Y, Z, V), i(U, Z, W).
% A6
i(X, X, e).
```

Then I wanted to prove the theorem, so i typed "i(b,a,c)" in Prolog console, and I got following error message:

```
?- i(b,a,c).
ERROR: Out of global-stack.
ERROR: No room for exception term.  Aborting.
ERROR: Out of global-stack.
ERROR: No room for exception term.  Aborting.
ERROR: Out of global-stack.
ERROR: No room for exception term.  Aborting.
% Execution Aborted
```

Please help me, thank you very much!

Comment: I would suspect that `i(U, Z, W) :- i(X, Y, U), i(Y, Z, V), i(X, V, W).` and `i(X, V, W) :- i(X, Y, U), i(Y, Z, V), i(U, Z, W).` would send prolog into a recursive stack spin.

Comment: As a logical theory, Prolog is not complete.

Comment: I'm not sure if your "conversion" is actually sufficient to prove the result, either. For example, nothing really says that given `i(A, B, C), i(A, B, D)` we can conclude `C=D`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Do you have any suggestion of converting A5 into clauses?

Comment: @aschepler I don't know, all the information and theorem were given by my professor, and he said he can prove the theorem by doing some extra steps: he used KB and A7 to conclude i(a,c,b) then he added i(a,c,b) to the KB and then he concluded i(b,c,a). Then he did the same to prove i(b, a, c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The A51 and A52 clauses are **left-recursive**, which causes the out-of-stack errors. The canonical solution for dealing with left-recursion in Prolog is to use a system supporting **tabling** (e.g. XSB, YAP, SWI-Prolog, B-Prolog, or Ciao). But there's another issue in your code. The A3 and A4 clauses can result in the creation of cyclic terms. For example, loading only clause A3:

```
?- i(X, X, Y), cyclic_term(X).
X = comp(X),
Y = e.
```

If you comment out the A3 and A4 clauses and add at the top of your source file the directive:

```
:- table(i/3).
```

You will get:

```
?- i(b,a,c).
true.
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, could you explain what does the tabling mean? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Snowpanther See e.g. http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling